# How to automatically download javadocs with Gradle?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, javadoc

None of the javadocs for my third party libraries are showing up in eclipse. In my top level build.gradle I have added this to no effect:

```
allprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    eclipse {
        classpath {
            downloadJavadoc = true
            downloadSources = true
        }
    }
...
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems good.
when you run the eclipse task , the location of the javadoc files will be added in the .classpath. Go through the below link.
https://dzone.com/articles/gradle-goodness-download-javadoc-files-for-depende